# Fresh 21.10 install cannot resolve .local hostnames

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, mdns

I am having a hard time getting a fresh Kubuntu 21.10 install to access other machines on my network using `hostname.local` resolution.

I have the following:

- Kubuntu 21.10 install named `jwork` - this is the problem machine
- Ubuntu Server 20.04 install named `gimli`
- Raspbian install named `plexpi`

gimli and plexpi can ping `gimli.local`, `plexpi.local` and `jwork.local` and get a response.

jwork gets no response from any of those, but does get a response from `jwork`.

Related fact: Spotify on jwork cannot see any devices to cast to on my network. It could when I was on Manjaro before I switched to Kubuntu.

Here are the contents of various files that I have worked out might be relevant:

### /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

### /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
MulticastDNS=yes
LLMNR=yes
```

### /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

`libnss-mdns` is installed

### /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/mdns.conf

```
[connection]
connection.mdns=2
connection.llmnr=2
```

### /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf

```
[server]
domain-name=getoutoftheway
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
```

`avahi-daemon` is installed

### resolvectl status

```
Global
       Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp7s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

For comparison, here's gimli's `resolvectl status`:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      ...more arpa addresses
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test     

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS    
DefaultRoute setting: yes    
       LLMNR setting: yes    
MulticastDNS setting: no     
  DNSOverTLS setting: no     
      DNSSEC setting: no     
    DNSSEC supported: no     
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      1.0.0.1
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get jwork to start resolving .local domains correctly?

Comment: Are the other two computers set to 1.1.1.1 also?

Comment: @mchid all three are set to 1.1.1.1 (my post has gimli's info at the bottom as well as jwork's).

I don't think I set that manually on gimli or jwork, I think they pulled it from my router?

Edit: yeah I spent a while trying to get jwork to show my router's IP instead of 1.1.1.1 which didn't solve the problem, and then realised gimli works while showing 1.1.1.1.